# How to set all google dependencies to compatible versions?

Tags: android, dependencies

The following is my build Gradle dependency which works.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/jama-1.0.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/la4j-0.4.5.jar')
    //implementation group: 'org.ejml', name: 'ejml-all', version: '0.37.1'
    //implementation group: 'org.openimaj', name: 'openimaj', version: '1.3.1', ext: 'pom'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math3', version: '3.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'

}
```

But when I try to add the following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0
```

I get an error on the following.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

I looked at another answer to a similar question which asks to make all google dependency versions compatible. But I don't know which version is compatible with what? Is there any way to know this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the `support` dependency from the `play-services-ads`

```
implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

Comment: In the terminal, you can type `gradlew dependencies`. You will see the dependencies tree of your app and the different versions of the support lib.

Comment: I am using windows.  Does this command work in command prompt? Could you specify which terminal?

Comment: In the terminal window of your Android Studio for example